# Merging .ts files from m3u8 to a single mp4 using Python on GAE (no ffmpeg)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video

I am trying to download and merge a list of files from a m3u8 manifest to a single mp4 video file using python on GAE.
Right now I am downloading the files and appending them to the the same 'new' file in the order they are in the playlist. The new file is playable but only with some of the players. Probably because most of the players can't figure out the file type - there is no container.
Looking for a way to write the mp4 container metadata to the merged file.

The code is in python and should work on Google app engine. This is what I got for now (working but without the container tags).

```
    gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(filename, 'w', content_type='video/mp4')
    response = urlfetch.fetch(link)
    base_link = link.rsplit('/', 1)[0]

    if response.content:
        lines = response.content.split('\n')
        logging.info('merge_m3u8() - got response for m3u8: %s' % response.content)
        ts_filenames = [line.rstrip() for line in lines if line.rstrip().endswith('.ts')]
        logging.info('merge_m3u8() - found %d items in playlist' % len(ts_filenames))
        for ts_file in ts_filenames:
            logging.info('merge_m3u8() - downloading file %s' % ts_file)
            response = urlfetch.fetch('%s/%s' % (base_link, ts_file))
            gcs_file.write(response.content)

        logging.info('merge_m3u8() - closing file %s' % filename)
        gcs_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a container, the container is TS. Parsing TS and writing mp4 can be done without ffmpeg, but its a lot of code. (I wrote a version of this in C specifically designed to be as small as possible and it was still over 2000 SLOC). The formats are different enough so that you can not simply add mp4 metdata. You must demux and remux. There are other options besides ffmpeg however. such as mp4box.